# How to add "save" and "save & stay" buttons on a new product tab Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Good day all.
I'm coding a simple module in Prestashop 1.6, which add a new tab on the product page in the back office with some new product attributes.
I've added the new tab and the content I need in it, but I'd like to insert the standard "save" and "save & stay" buttons. Looking at the [helper form class](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperForm+class) **could be something I can use**, but how? where and how I use that?

here is part of the code of the module of the hook:

```
public function prepareNewTab()
{

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(

        'isThisProductNew' => $this->getisThisProductStillNew((int)Tools::getValue('id_product')),
        'howManyDays' => Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT'),
        'date_add' => $this->getProductDateAdd((int)Tools::getValue('id_product')),
        'strtotime_days' =>$this->strtotime_date()
    ));


}


    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra(){
        $this->prepareNewTab();

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/newProductsTab.tpl');
    }
```

**I'm sure I don't have to build the buttons from scratch in the tpl**, can someone leads me to the right way? I havn't seen any example around (specific for this case I mean).

Answer (score 0):

In your custom tpl file, add the below code for submit buttons:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitAddproduct" class="btn btn-default pull-right" disabled="disabled"><i class="process-icon-loading"></i> {l s='Save'}</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submitAddproductAndStay" class="btn btn-default pull-right" disabled="disabled"><i class="process-icon-loading"></i> {l s='Save and stay'}</button>
```

By default your form is displaying under form so that whenever user clieck on any of these button, system will identify the action according button name and work accordingly.

Comment: Mh, ok, I thought the helper form class should take care of this without adding them directly to the template, but if this is the only way, I'll go for it... :/